# Downloading list of files using a REST Service

Tags: java, rest, file

I am new to Java and i am currently trying to download a list of files. I  take this code as base to download a single file and it is working.

```
package com.java2novice.restful;
 
import java.io.File;
 
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ResponseBuilder;
 
@Path("/download")
public class RestDownloadService {
 
    @GET
    @Path("/service-record")
    @Produces("application/pdf")
    public Response getFile() {
  
        File file = new File("C:\java2novice\employee_1415.pdf");
  
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=\"employee_1415.pdf\"");
        return response.build();
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me how i can modify this code so that i will be able to downlaod a list of files?

Comment: Do you want to send back the list of files as a package (e.g. Zip)? Or do you want to download each one individually?

Comment: I want to download each one individually..

Comment: just add page to list the files, add a parameter to `getFile(unique file id)`, then download each file seperately.